# Cannot find module 'dotenv' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, dotenv

I'm trying to learn Nestjs with Angular 10 & MondoDB. My problem while starting server I'm getting an error "Cannot find module 'dotenv' or its corresponding type declarations". I did everything to prevent this error.

I did npm-install-peers, downgrade typescript but still getting big list of error in case of try to install any dependency. Please help me.

```
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 
15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure 
binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see 
https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because 
it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 
(node_modules\rollup\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted 
{"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\watchpack- 
chokidar2\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted 
{"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\webpack-dev- 
server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted 
{"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1001.7 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.9 < 4.1 but none is 
installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/common@10.1.6 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.5.3 but none is installed. You must 
install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@10.1.6 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.9 <4.1 but none is installed. 
You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/core@10.1.6 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.5.3 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/forms@10.1.6 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.5.3 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@10.1.6 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.5.3 but none is installed. You must 
install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @nestjs/common@7.5.4 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@^0.1.12 but none is installed. You 
must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @nestjs/common@7.5.4 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @nestjs/core@7.5.4 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@^0.1.12 but none is installed. You 
must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @nestjs/core@7.5.4 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @nestjs/mongoose@7.1.2 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@^0.1.12 but none is installed. 
You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @nestjs/mongoose@7.1.2 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must 
install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@10.1.7 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.9 < 4.1 but none is installed. You 
must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EINVAL
npm ERR! EINVAL: invalid argument, read
```

---

**Edit:** I've also tried installing [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) however I still getting same list of errors as per above.

Comment: well, before you try to fix the dotenv error, did you read/fix the other warnings npm is telling you?